# Targeting the OrbitControls to a 3D object position avoiding it's placement to the center of the screen

Tags: three.js

I am trying to orbit around an object which is not exactly at the origin of the world. When I try to target the orbitControls to an object which is at some random location, then by default behavior, the object is moved at the center of the canvas and camera moves around it appearing like the targeted object is at the origin.

Image when green cube is targeted by orbitcontrols and green cube appears at origin as it actually is.
[image]

Image when blue cube is targeted by orbitcontrols and blue cube appears at the origin which it is not.
[image]

Same with red cube.
[image]

I want the object to appear where it is and camera to orbit around it avoiding the targeted object to appear at the origin. I have seen some websites with such behavior.

Please let me know how can we implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the focus point of `OrbitControls` by changing the [target](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=orbit#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls.target) property. If for example the controls should orbit around the blue box, do this:

```js
controls.target.copy( blueBox.position );
controls.update();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mugen87

I did the same for the blueBox and the redBox but that places the blueBox or the redBox at the center of the canvas...I want the placement to remain unaffected by even if the control targets the corner of the screen. Is there a way to do that?